# Create a folder after pressing the button

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, grayscale

When I pressed the button Load Data, the new folder was created, but only after I closed the application.

It's a method where I open a window, where I can choose o image. Next I convert a image to greyscale and try to save greyscale image to new folder.

Code:

```
    def getFile(self):
        #Open window to choose file
        self.filePath, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self.window, 'Choose an image', "${HOME}","Formats: (*.png )")

        for filePath in self.filePath:
            image = Image.open(filePath)
            #convert image to greyscale
            img_grey = image.convert('L')

            filename = os.path.basename(filePath)
            #make new folder
            os.makedirs(self.output_dir, exist_ok=True)
            #join a filname from original image to image after greyscale
            output_path = os.path.join(self.output_dir, filename)
            #save a greyscale image to new folder
            img_grey.save(output_path)
```

output_dir I defined in def **init**(method create by me):

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):


    def __init__(self):

        self.filePath = ''
        self.currentDir = os.getcwd()
        self.images = []
        self.output_dir = os.path.abspath('..\\greyscale_images')
```

Full code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'app.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.9
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from pathlib import Path
from Code.show_data import showData
from Code.pyRadiomics import extractRadiomics
from Code.data import CustomDataset
from PIL import ImageOps, Image
import numpy as np


class Ui_MainWindow(object):


    def __init__(self):

        self.filePath = ''
        self.currentDir = os.getcwd()
        self.images = []
        self.output_dir = os.path.abspath('..\\greyscale_images')

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.window = MainWindow
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(951, 633)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setEnabled(True)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 541, 391))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.noNormaButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame)
        self.noNormaButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 250, 141, 20))
        self.noNormaButton.setObjectName("noNormaButton")
        self.minMaxButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame)
        self.minMaxButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 280, 171, 20))
        self.minMaxButton.setObjectName("minMaxButton")
        self.meanStdButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame)
        self.meanStdButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 310, 181, 20))
        self.meanStdButton.setObjectName("meanStdButton")
        self.perButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame)
        self.perButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 340, 161, 20))
        self.perButton.setObjectName("perButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 200, 121, 31))
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.area1Button = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame)
        self.area1Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 110, 141, 20))
        self.area1Button.setObjectName("area1Button")
        self.area2Button = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame)
        self.area2Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 130, 141, 20))
        self.area2Button.setObjectName("area2Button")
        self.bothButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame)
        self.bothButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 150, 141, 20))
        self.bothButton.setObjectName("bothButton")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 121, 31))
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 171, 31))
        self.label_6.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frame)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 551, 391))
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(186, 188, 162);")
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.widget_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.widget)
        self.widget_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 191, 151))
        self.widget_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(210, 204, 204);")
        self.widget_5.setObjectName("widget_5")
        self.widget_6 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.widget)
        self.widget_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 200, 191, 171))
        self.widget_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(210, 204, 204);")
        self.widget_6.setObjectName("widget_6")
        self.csvButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.csvButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 210, 150, 50))
        self.csvButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(210, 204, 204);")
        self.csvButton.setObjectName("csvButton")
        self.statusLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.statusLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 270, 151, 51))
        self.statusLabel.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.statusLabel.setStyleSheet("")
        self.statusLabel.setText("")
        self.statusLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.statusLabel.setObjectName("statusLabel")
        self.widget_6.raise_()
        self.widget_5.raise_()
        self.csvButton.raise_()
        self.statusLabel.raise_()
        self.widget.raise_()
        self.noNormaButton.raise_()
        self.minMaxButton.raise_()
        self.meanStdButton.raise_()
        self.perButton.raise_()
        self.label.raise_()
        self.area1Button.raise_()
        self.area2Button.raise_()
        self.bothButton.raise_()
        self.label_5.raise_()
        self.label_6.raise_()
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 420, 541, 201))
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.loadDataButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.loadDataButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 110, 150, 50))
        self.loadDataButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(210, 204, 204);")
        self.loadDataButton.setObjectName("loadDataButton")
        self.showButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.showButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 130, 150, 50))
        self.showButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(210, 204, 204);")
        self.showButton.setObjectName("showButton")
        self.button3D = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.frame_2)
        self.button3D.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 170, 131, 21))
        self.button3D.setObjectName("button3D")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_2)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 10, 121, 31))
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.LoadFolderButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.LoadFolderButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 50, 150, 50))
        self.LoadFolderButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(210, 204, 204);")
        self.LoadFolderButton.setObjectName("LoadFolderButton")
        self.widget_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frame_2)
        self.widget_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 541, 201))
        self.widget_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(186, 188, 162);")
        self.widget_4.setObjectName("widget_4")
        self.widget_4.raise_()
        self.loadDataButton.raise_()
        self.showButton.raise_()
        self.button3D.raise_()
        self.label_3.raise_()
        self.LoadFolderButton.raise_()
        self.frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 20, 381, 601))
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.loadRadioDataButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_3)
        self.loadRadioDataButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 90, 150, 50))
        self.loadRadioDataButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(210, 204, 204);")
        self.loadRadioDataButton.setObjectName("loadRadioDataButton")
        self.classifyButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_3)
        self.classifyButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 150, 150, 50))
        self.classifyButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(210, 204, 204);")
        self.classifyButton.setObjectName("classifyButton")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_3)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 10, 121, 31))
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_3)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 160, 121, 31))
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.widget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frame_3)
        self.widget_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 381, 601))
        self.widget_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(186, 188, 162);")
        self.widget_3.setObjectName("widget_3")
        self.show_classifier = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget_3)
        self.show_classifier.setEnabled(True)
        self.show_classifier.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 240, 350, 350))
        self.show_classifier.setText("")
        self.show_classifier.setObjectName("show_classifier")
        self.widget_3.raise_()
        self.loadRadioDataButton.raise_()
        self.classifyButton.raise_()
        self.label_2.raise_()
        self.label_4.raise_()
        self.widget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 961, 641))
        self.widget_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(81, 93, 78);")
        self.widget_2.setObjectName("widget_2")
        self.widget_2.raise_()
        self.frame.raise_()
        self.frame_2.raise_()
        self.frame_3.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.loadDataButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.getFile())
        self.showButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.showImages())
        self.csvButton.clicked.connect((lambda: self.radiomics()))


    def getFile(self):
        #Open window to choose file
        self.filePath, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self.window, 'Choose an image', "${HOME}","Formats: (*.png )")

        for filePath in self.filePath:
            image = Image.open(filePath)
            #convert image to greyscale
            img_grey = image.convert('L')

            filename = os.path.basename(filePath)
            #make new folder
            os.makedirs(self.output_dir, exist_ok=True)
            #join a filname from original image to image after greyscale
            output_path = os.path.join(self.output_dir, filename)
            #save a greyscale image to new folder
            img_grey.save(output_path)




            #greyImage = Image.open(output_path)
            #self.images.append(greyImage)

    def showImages(self):
        if self.images:
            print("Number of images:", len(self.images))
            showData(self.images)
        else:
            print("No files selected.")

    def radiomics(self):
        if self.radioButton.isChecked():
            extractRadiomics(self.images)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Textural analysis"))
        self.noNormaButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "No normalization"))
        self.minMaxButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Min-Max normalization"))
        self.meanStdButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Mean/Std normalization"))
        self.perButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Percentile normalization"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Normalization"))
        self.area1Button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.area2Button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.bothButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Both"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Segmentation"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Select the area to analyze:"))
        self.csvButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Generate CSV"))
        self.loadDataButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Load Data"))
        self.showButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Show Data"))
        self.button3D.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3D Image"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Data"))
        self.LoadFolderButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Load Folder"))
        self.loadRadioDataButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Load Data"))
        self.classifyButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Classify"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Classification"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Classifier SVM"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So I want clicked the button Load Data, choose images, next this images are converted to greyscale, and after that they are saved in a new folder, which is created immediately by the Load Data button.

Is it even possible to create a new folder while the application is running? If so, how can I do it ?
I'm new in Python. If you need more information, please write.

Comment: Please could you try to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?